# Required Guidance in Designing MPU6050 I2C Schematic for Daisy-Chaining

Tags: arduino, pcb-design, kicad, mpu

I am designing a breakout board using the MPU6050 chip. This is what I have so far, I need some advice/guidance about things I may have overlooked.

I intend on daisy chaining about 8-10 of these MPU6050 Breakout boards for my design, so there's a few modifications I have made from the existing breakout boards (Adafruit MPU6050 / GY-521)

[image]

- My design requires me to daisy-chain multiple, thus I do not have a Pull-Up Resistor from SDA/SCL to +3V3. (Daisy-chaining multiple GY-521 boards caused issues with parallel pull-up resistors becoming too low)
- Since the SDA/SCL Level shift only needs to be done once, those will be done on the Arduino side. (Bi-Directional Level Shifter)
- AD0 -- maybe I could add a Voltage divider since I know I will power it off a 5V Arduino board.

Does the Schematic look all right before I start wiring it up?
I want the footprint to be as small as possible and print it on a flexible base.
Please let me know if you have any advice/suggestions. Thank you!

================================================================

**Edit:** I have made some changes to the schematic based on the comments, I figured, since all of the MPUs function at 3.3V, why not use just 1 LDO to regulate the voltage? Following is the updated Schematic, please let me know if you see any other issues.

***Individual MPU6050 Schematic***
[image]

***Schematic with the Power Regulation and I2C Level Shifts, along with
a DEMUX to allow toggle***
[image]

Answer (score 1):

> I intend on daisy chaining about 8-10 of these MPU6050 Breakout boards ...

You can't.

First, the capacitance across each line and ground will be a limiting factor i.e. as you add multiple nodes you'll bring extra capacitances which interact with the pull-up resistors and create a low pass filter chopping off the sharp edges of the pulses (or in simpler terms, causing communication problems).

And second, I2C devices communicating over the same SDA-SCL lines must have unique addresses (unless the application requires one-direction communication i.e. from master to slave only), otherwise there's going to be collision i.e. communication problems.

In your application MPU6xxx devices will send data to the master but since they have only a single pin for address change (AD0 - address LSB), you can have only two of them on the same SDA-SCL line (AD0 = 0 and AD0 = 1).

If you have 4 to 8 independent I2C lines or if you plan to use a I2C multiplexer then things might be different.

> AD0 -- maybe I could add a Voltage divider since I know I will power it off a 5V Arduino board.

You don't have to. You can add a [solder bridge](https://forums.ni.com/t5/image/serverpage/image-id/171500i159C4D644993D319?v=v2) or [jumper pins](https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/41XLe0USu7L.jpg) to tie the address pin to either 3V3 (AD0 = 1) or GND (AD0 = 0).

EDIT: As Justme stated in their comment, you can use AD0 pin of each device as chip select (CS): If you want to fetch a data from a specific node then set it address to, say, 1 and the rest's to 0. This requires one extra pin for each device. If the CS signal will come from an Arduino (or something else), voltage divider will work but, even if you know the voltage levels of incoming signal, it's still good to consider a voltage translator instead (and it's also good for noise immunity):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f7sbl7.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: It might be possible for short distances. And the addressing can be solved by a chip select per device - keep all chips at one address except the one you want to communicate with, assuming the address is not latched of course.

Comment: @Justme good point. I'll add that to my answer.

Comment: I see your point with the Capacitances adding up and causing problems. I will need to look into getting rid of those.

- About the address issue, I have that taken care of by connecting the AD0 to a digital gate on the uC and setting all of them high/low, then toggling just one of them to read the data.

I am debating between just having a simple MOSFET based Voltage shifter and an LDO.